# Запись лога log4j разных уровней в разные файлы

Tags: java, log4j

Мне необходимо, чтоб для класса Х сообщения уровня INFO и ниже записывались в один файл, и одновременно с этим сообщения для этогоже класса Х уровня ERROR записывались бы в другой файл. Как при этом надо настроить log4j.properties? Желательно на примере.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Создайте в конфигурации два разных аппендера с необходимыми вам свойствами.

1. Для "настройки" уровня логирования конкретного аппендера используйте свойство `threshold` Пример:

   ```
   log4j.appender.file1.threshold=WARN
   log4j.appender.file2.threshold=INFO
   ```
2. Использование фильтров

   ```
   log4j.appender.file1.filter.a=org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter
   log4j.appender.file1.filter.a.LevelMin=WARN
   log4j.appender.file1.filter.a.LevelMax=FATAL
   log4j.appender.file1.filter.a.AcceptOnMatch=TRUE
   ```

Comment: Спасибо, реализовал первый вариант.